# Why stateless widget rebuild on entering new data

Tags: flutter

I have created a screen for entering data and display,
with a stateful widget HomeScreen

I have used two widget inside home screen which are entry form and display data , both are stateless widgets...but Whenever I add records it changes colour of stateless widget's card as I have set as random colour. that means that widget is also rebuild eventhought it is stateless..

Y its happening as I don't want to change colour on entering each records.

or looks like I am having a wrong concept of stateless nd stateful..

I think widget which is set as stateless remains unchanged...

Correct me If I am wrong..

here is my 3 files

HomeScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'displaydata.dart';
import 'entryform.dart';
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List <double> numbers=[44.43,65.64,35.64,76.64];
  void _addRecord(double num)
  {
   numbers.add(num);
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('okay'),),
      body: Column(children: [
        EntryForm(_addRecord),
        DisplayData(list: numbers,),
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

EntryForm.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class EntryForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function addrecord;
  EntryForm(this.addrecord);
  final txtname=TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(255), 1),
      child: Padding(

        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: txtname,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                  addrecord(double.parse(txtname.text));
                }, child: Text('Add Record')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

DisplayData.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DisplayData extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<double> list;
  DisplayData({required this.list});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 400,
      child: ListView.builder(
         itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
             return Text(list[index].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),);
          }),
    );
  }
}

``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when a stateful widget rebuilds, it rebuilds entirely with its children included no matter stateful or stateless they are, unless the child widget is marked as `const` (then rebuild of a child won't happen as it shall remain the same anyway).

Particular in your example, `onPressed` triggers parent function `_addRecord` which calls `setState()`. Parent widget rebuilds whenever `setState` is called with new parameters and because its child `EntryForm()` depends on those it has to be rebuilt as well.

Hopes it'll add some to your understanding of state.

Comment: Thanks...but suppose I don't want to change entry form colour on each new record added...keepint it as same as stateless. Means prevent from rebuilding that new form widget...Any idea?

Comment: have placed randomcolor is only for checking whether it is rebuild or not...

Comment: well, my guess will be removing color to an external global variable in this particular file like `final Color _myColor = Color.fromRGBO(...)` outside the class `EntryForm` and then use it in `EntryForm` by referencing as such: `return Card( color: _myColor)`. For example. This way the random value will be calculated only once and no rebuilds will affect it. Also you can explore different state management solutions, such as Provider to make it more safe and flexible.

Comment: "it rebuilds entirely with its children included" I think you are wrong or I don't understand something. It rebuilds only those widgets in tree that indeed did change, otherwise it just points to already existing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are right and wrong both at the same time.

Your statement 'I think widget which is set as stateless remains unchanged...' - This is true.

So Stateless widget is an immutable widget that cannot react to state changes and re-render, you will have to use some form of state management.

You just have the wrong concept of Stateful Widget. Stateful widget will rebuild the whole widget when you call setState(). Does not matter if you have stateless widgets inside a stateful widget, the whole stateful widget will be rebuilt if you call setState().

Comment: Thanks...but suppose I don't want to change entry form colour on each new record added...keepint it as same as stateless. Means prevent from rebuilding that new form widget...Any idea?

Comment: In that case you have to use State management package. Only the data that changed will be built and the rest will stay same. You can look into Getx Flutter.